# Difference between exim.conf and config.autogenerated

Tags: exim

I executed `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and it generated `/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated`. I believe that this is the master configuration. However on our older server with an older version of Exim I have seen `exim.conf` in the `/etc` folder. What is the purpose of this file and how can I generate it? Is there a tool that can generate it and is it recommended to have this file?

Answer (score 1):

`/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated` is the file that `exim4` actually references for its run-time configuration.

On Debian this file is built from the configuration and macro files in `/etc/exim4`. For example, `exim4.conf.template` is one version of the starting point, and the macro definitions set in `update-exim4.conf.conf` are added in.

You can rebuild the target file:

```
update-exim4.conf
```

And/or you can restart `exim4` with the new configuration file (this also runs `update-exim4.conf` itself, so no need for a separate manual step):

```
systemctl restart exim4    # or: service exim4 restart
```

Comment: `service exim4 restart` or `systemctl restart exim4`  will itself invoke `update-exim4.conf`

Comment: @Jasen thank you. Answer updated; please feel free to improve it as necessary.